# Воспрос не сложный, но я на нем застряд на 3 часа. Связан с if, elif и else

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, if

Нужно, чтобы слово "программист" склонялось к числам от 0 до 1000.  Например: 1 программист, 2 программиста, 5 программистов.
Я перепробовал казалось бы все, что можно, и конвертировать в строку и не делать этого и с "x % 10", но ничего не помогает. Буду безгранично благодарен за ответ и, если не сложно, за рекомендацию по поводу того, как нужно было правильно загуглить или сформулировать этот вопрос.

```
_count = int(input())
_str = str(_count)
lastStr = int(_str[-1:])

if lastStr == 1:
    print('программист')
elif lastStr == 2 or 3 or 4:
    print('программиста')
elif lastStr == 0 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9:
    print('программистов')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. У вас недоработана грамматика. Числительные с 11 по 14 (а также 111, 10013 и т.п.), хоть и оканчиваются на 1/2/3/4, но склоняться должны как "программистов". Т.е., логика должна быть несколько сложнее.
2. конструкция `_str[-1:]` вернет срез, начинающийся с символа с индексом -1 (то бишь, последнего) и оканчивающийся символом с индексом 0, то бишь первым. Не находите, что это похоже не бред? Достаточно просто `_str[-1]`.

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное за подробное обьяснение! У меня сейчас такая радость, как у ребенка какого-то, потому что так четко и оперативно за несколько минут или десятков минут такие поднобные обьяснения, это очень здорово! Еще раз спасибо!))

Comment: И все же, как мне следовало бы загуглить этот вопрос, чтобы лишний раз не тревощить людей?

Comment: Для поиска Plural-Forms gettext. Выдаст правила формообразования числительных для разных языков

Answer (score 0):

```
s = int(input("Введите кол-во: "))
n1 = 'программистов'
n2 = 'программист'
n3 = 'программиста'
if s >= 0:
    if s == 0:
        print(s, n1)
    elif s % 100 >= 10 and s % 100 <= 20:
        print(s, n1)
    elif s % 10 == 1:
        print(s, n2)
    elif s % 10 >= 2 and s % 10 <= 4:
        print(s, n3)
    else:
        print(s, n1)
else:
    print("Число должно быть положительным.")

Попробуй так :)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Все отлично работает! Что правда, практически ничего не понятно, но когда больше знаний наберусь, обязательно вернусь и разберусь с этой темой)

Answer (score 0):

Вместо

```
elif lastStr == 2 or 3 or 4:
```

нужно писать

```
elif lastStr == 2 or lastStr == 3 or lastStr == 4:
```

или — красивее —

```
elif lastStr in (2, 3, 4):
```

То же самое для следующего `elif`.

Answer (score 0):

Как правильно заметил [Инквизитор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/290668/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80), нужно учитывать не только числа от 0 до 9, а также 10-19 (из-за правил склонения числительных в русском языке).

> ```
> lastStr = int(_str[-1:])
> _str = str(_count)
> ```

Является лишним. Вам не нужно знать на какую цифру оканчивается введенное число. Лучше всего узнать, каким будет остаток от деления этого числа на 10 и 100 (100 используется для проверки чисел от 11 до 19).

Например: если мы делим 5 на 10, то остаток будет 5 и тогда мы будем проверять этот результат на условие "Принадлежит ли число к диапазону от 5 до 9". Таким образом, мы создадим условия под каждое правило склонения. В случае проверки чисел от 11 до 19, нам нужно проверить остаток от деления на 100 (например, 16 % 100 будет 16, 112 % 100 будет 12 и т.п.).

> `elif lastStr == 2 or 3 or 4:`

Не нужно так много раз прописывать `or`. Используйте `in` или, в случае последовательности, `range`.

Ниже я доработал ваш код:

```
_count = int(input())
    
if (_count % 10 == 0) or  (_count % 10 in range(5, 10)) or (_count % 100 in range(5, 21)):
    print(_count, 'программистов')
elif _count % 10 == 1:
    print(_count, 'программист')
elif _count % 10 in (2, 3, 4):
    print(_count, 'программиста')
```